# How can we be certain that Ryugu is a remnant of the material that did not form planets?

Tags: asteroid, hayabusa2, ryugu

Its mentioned here https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/feb/22/japans-hayabusa-2-successfully-touches-down-on-ryugu-asteroid  that Ryugu is a part of the Solar System material that did not get swept into forming a planet. But how can we be sure that it was not created later for example by an asteroid striking Mars or some other planet? Why do we think its "primordial"?

Comment: This is a great question! It's certainly on-topic here (primordialness is part of the reason for the space exploration mission) but the topic of solar system evolution is probably better for [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), I think there are more people able to address that there. If you don't receive any answers here after a while, you could consider moving it. *Welcome to Space!*

Comment: Thanks. Posted there too: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29825/how-can-we-be-certain-that-ryugu-is-a-remnant-of-the-material-that-did-not-form

Comment: Oh, in Stack Exchange cross-posting the exact same question on two sites is strongly discouraged. I meant that you could ask there instead of here, or wait a while and if no answer, then delete here and post there instead. Why don't you take a little time and decide which site you want to keep your original question, and then *modify the question* on the other site so that it isn't the same question simply cross-posted.